# Can I assign keyboard shortcuts to laptop-specific commands?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, fn-key

I mean the combinations like Fn + F2 which switches wireless.

Since I don't have a Fn key on my USB keyboard, can I assign global shortcuts to, for example decrease the screen brightness from my USB keyboard?

Answer (score 1):

try your mouse pad software in control panel /mouse hardware/properties synaptics management program is default on all laptops use it like touch screen on mobile:zoom, edgemotion, scroll, u can do alot a mobile screen can dooptions allow appliction or keystoke macro assignment to corners. or mousepad and  hidden. buttons eg in corner of touchpads and size u want this short cuts